# I want to make a border in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]I have a picture with a border, I want to cut the center out and just keep the border to put around another picture. Using Adobe Photoshop CC. I've tried cutting out the middle with a rectangular marquee tool and using the quick select wand, but neither are giving me the results I want.

Comment: Welcome along - ok, you will not get much help unless you can post the picture, and tell us what software you have.

Comment: And what you've tried

Comment: How do i post a picture? It doesn't say anything about uploading a picture.  I'm using Adobe Photoshop

Comment: Hi Dani, when you click [edit] there's an Image icon above the text field that lets you upload images to IMGUR and post them. If you're struggling then just upload to IMGUR and post the link and someone will fix it for you. Also, when replying to comments use `@usersname` like `@ryan` or `@digitallightcraft` so that it pings the person you're replying to. You'll get an answer quicker that way.

Comment: @Ryan I've added information and a picture help please

Comment: How did using the magic wand not lead to what you want? It would be my first tool of choice.

Comment: @RadLexus It was also my tool of choice, but it just automatically selected everything right out to the edges. It didn't stop at the streamers like I hoped it would

Comment: Are you sure you're on the correct layer or that your tolerance isn't set too high?

Answer (score 2):

On the top menu

Select>Color Range

Then click on any white part of the image and move the tolerancy slider to get more or less accurate on the selection of the color.

when you click OK you'll get a selection of all the white color on the image, if you press delete you'll remove all the white from the image.

Comment: Hello DBD and thanks for the contribution! Let us know if you have any questions about how the site works

Comment: Not what was asked: "I want to cut the center out". This method will select all white pixels in the entire image.

Answer (score 2):

1. Bring up the **Channels** panel then control click the RGB channel at the top.

[image: Channels panel]

2. Switch back to **Layers** then press the Delete key...

[image: Before...]
[image: After...]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the magic wand tool you could try the **magnetic lasso tool**. This tool will snap to the edges of the border, but will not select the white background behind the border.

If you want a bit more refined result you could invert your selection and apply a slight feather to it. This will make the line a bit smoother. Or instead of a feather you could use the refine selection option to further optimize your selection.

Comment: Hello Tirza and thanks for your contribution! Let us know if you have any questions about how the site works

Comment: The magnetic lasso tool would be far too much work for such a simple task with the standard magic wand tool. So long as the poster turns the tolerance right down to say 2 or 3 they should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

For better results, you could use pen tool instead of magic wand tool in Photoshop.
Using pen tool create shape around the border and than make selection of it.
After selection just crop it using ctr+shift+i to invert selections.
It will give you a border with more refined result.